# How To test in rspec if file is deleted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I would like to know how to test in rspec is specific file is deleted.  Here is code that I am testing

```
def check_status
  filename = File.join('test', 'status.txt')
  File.delete(filename ) if File.exist?(filename)
end
```

Here is test:

```
before do
  allow(File).to receive(:exist?).and_return(true)
  allow(File).to receive(:delete)
end

it {expect(File).to receive(:delete).with("test/status.txt") }
```

I am getting error

```
(File (class)).delete("test/status.txt")
    expected: 1 time with arguments: ("test/status.txt")
    received: 0 times
```

Could you please help me with this issue. I am sure that my code delete the file, but in tests it receive it 0 times.

Comment: I guess you can check if file still exists after delete. `allow(File).to receive(:exist?).and_return(false)`

Comment: your suggestion will always return true because  I have code :  allow(File).to receive(:exist?).and_return(true). I want to check if  delete is called on specific file.

Comment: where do you call `check_status`?

Comment: I call it inside function that Iam testing check_status . I use binding.pry to cehck if it is really called and it is.

Comment: class Execution

def run
    check_status
end
end 

in test I have subject { execution.run }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your spec, it appears that you are mocking and stubbing correctly, but you never call `check_status`, so the stubs and mocks don't get used. You could change your example to something like:

```
it 'deletes the file' do
  expect(File).to receive(:delete).with("test/status.txt")
  MyModel.check_status
end
```

It would be better still to test this with an actual file, instead of mocks and stubs, so that it also tests that the file is in the correct location, that you have the necessary permissions, etc.

Comment: You have to set the expectation(s) before calling `check_status` (or use spies and `have_received`)

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, this is not working for me. I tried this before.

Comment: MyModel has method run,   which call method check_status that is private.  I am not able to do something like MyModel.check_status

Comment: @ivan you accepted this answer, although the proposed solution is not working for you?

Comment: actually it is ok . It is not working as I excepted. But I learn a lot from this solution.  I  changed method check_status to public instead private. After that it is working.

Answer (score 0):

updated question

```
 File.delete('status.txt') if File.exist?('status.txt')
```

Solution

```
context '#delete' do
    it 'deletes the file' do
      allow(File).to receive(:exist?).and_return(true)
      allow(File).to receive(:delete)
      expect(File).to receive(:delete).with("status.txt")
      # suppose check_status method is defined in TempClass
      delete = TempClass.new
      delete.check_status
    end
  end
```